# Toggling between filtering blank and filled cells in a table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Im fairly new to VBA and Im working on a set of filter macros for a table of customers.

Im currently using two macros: one to filter out blank cells in a column and the other to filter out filled cells in said column. It works but I want to incorporate it into a single macro to toggle between two filter criteria and I was wondering whether it was possible to do it without using variables.
Im trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Heres what Im currently using:

```
Sub FilterEmpty()

Dim lo As ListObject
Dim iCol As Long

  Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    iCol = lo.ListColumns("Completed").Index
      lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:="<>" 
'replace <> with = for filled 

End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean by toggle between two macros ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base for toggling is to find out what the current value is, and pick the other. If it already is defined, then it would look something like this:

```
If lo.AutoFilter.Filters(iCol).Criteria1 = "<>" Then
    lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:="="
Else
    lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:="<>"
End If
```

This is enough if it already is defined. If it isn't, then you would have to add some extra checks:

```
Sub ToggleFilter()
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim iCol As Long

    Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    iCol = lo.ListColumns("Completed").Index

    On Error GoTo EH_ToggleFilter

    If lo.AutoFilter.Filters(iCol).Criteria1 = "<>" Then
        lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:="="
    Else
        lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:="<>"
    End If

    Exit Sub

EH_ToggleFilter:
    lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:="="

End Sub
```